# Android Media Player Compatible for every video platform?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am a newbie in android development and working on a project in which I can stream video from

```
a) my server storage i.e. using individual video URL generated from my server
b) youtube server via youtube video URL
```

Which would be the best third-party(free) library to achieve the purpose.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kindly refer https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats

Answer (score 0):

Use Exoplayer, a highly customisable player from google
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer